# Add labels above lines in OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

How to add labels above lines using OpenLayers?

Labels are added as follows:

```
    var styleMarkersLabels = new OpenLayers.Style( // стили для надписей узлов
                {
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                    labelYOffset: 10,
                    label: "${label}",
                    fontColor: 'red',
                    fontSize: 9,
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    labelOutlineColor: "black",
                    labelOutlineWidth: 1
                });
            var vectorPoint = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Узлы (надписи)",
            {
                styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(
                { "default": styleMarkersLabels,

                "select": { pointRadius: 20}
                })
            });
            map.addLayer(vectorPoint);

            function addPoint(lon, lat, title, ident, layr){
                var ttt = new OpenLayers.LonLat(parseFloat(lon), parseFloat(lat));
                ttt.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
                for (var k = 0; k < layr.features.length; k++) {
if(layr.features[k].attributes.PointId==ident) {
                        layr.features[k].move(ttt);
                        layr.features[k].attributes.label=title;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                var point0 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(parseFloat(lon), parseFloat(lat));
                point0.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
                layr.addFeatures(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point0, { label: title, name: title, PointId: ident }));
            }

            var lat2, lon2, title, ident;
            for (l = 0; l < nodesLabels_Count; l++) {
                lat2 = nodesLabels_arr[l]["points"][0]["lat"];
                lon2 = nodesLabels_arr[l]["points"][0]["lon"];
                title = nodesLabels_arr[l]["title"];
                ident = nodesLabels_arr[l]["ident"];
                addPoint(lon2, lat2, title, ident, map.layers[4]);
            }
```

But I got it: [image: The line on top of the label.]

Map here: http://softez.pp.ua/fiberms/fiberms/map.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Need add labels layer in the SelectFeature control (because the lines layer is added to SelectFeature control).
P.S. Thanks Alexandre from OpenLayers Mail List.